# Spring Integration as embedded alternative to standalone ESB

Tags: spring, jdbc, soa, esb, spring-integration

Does anybody has an experience with [Spring Integration](http://springframework.org/spring-integration) project as embedded ESB?

I'm highly interesting in such use cases as:

- Reading files from directory on schedule basis
- Getting data from JDBC data source
- Modularity and possibility to start/stop/redeploy module on the fly (e.g. one module can scan directory on schedule basis, another call query from jdbc  data source etc.)
- repeat/retry policy

**UPDATE:**

I found answers on all my questions except "Getting data from JDBC data source". Is it technically possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember, "ESB" is just a marketing term designed to sell more expensive software, it's not a magic bullet. You need to consider the specific jobs you need your software to do, and pick accordingly. If Spring Integration seems to fit the bill, I wouldn't be too concerned if it doesn't look much like an uber-expensive server installation.

Comment: I know :). I'm using in projects Mule ESB, but often it's overqualified and wish to use simplified and embedded one.

Answer (score 3):

The Spring Integration JDBC adapters are available in 2.0, and we just released GA last week. Here's the relevant section from the reference manual: http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/htmlsingle/#jdbc

Answer (score 2):

This link describes the [FileSucker](http://www.jroller.com/habuma/entry/spring_integration_return_of_the) with Spring Integration. Read up on your Enterprise Integration patterns for more info I think.

I kinda think you need to do a bit more investigation your self, or do a couple of tries on some of your usecases. Then we can discuss whats good and bad

Answer (score 2):

JDBC Adapters appear to be a [work in progress](https://jira.springframework.org/browse/INT-544).

Even if there is no specific adapter available, remember that Spring Integration is a thin wrapper around POJOs.  You'll be able to access JDBC in any component e.g. your service activators.

See [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=67734) for a solution based on a polling inbound channel adapter too.