# Can I use Spring Integration as a daemon in order to poll a directory?

Tags: spring, daemon, polling, spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration and I am considering using it in order to poll a directory for new files in order to process those files.

My question is: is Spring Integration **some sort of daemon** one can launch and that **one can use in order to poll a directory**?

Is this is possible can someone please direct me to relevant section of the official documentation on how to launch Spring Integration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to have a main method (or a WAR file if you want to deploy to Tomcat or another servlet container) that creates a Spring ApplicationContext (e.g. new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("file-poller.xml"))

It can run with a cron trigger, fixed-rate or fixed-delay trigger.

JMX operations can be exposed on Spring Integration's File adapter (or any adapter) by simply adding a single config element (e.g. <mbean-export>).

Bottom line: you REALLY do not need an ESB if you simply want a File poller to run continuously. You can have a single small config file and one line of code in a main method.

Visit the samples for more info: https://github.com/springsource/spring-integration-samples (look under basic/file specifically)

Hope that helps,
Mark

Answer (score 2):

Spring Integration is a part of framework, its not a programm or daemon.

What you cant do — is to configure Spring Integration to poll a directory, lunch JVM with Spring onboard  and poller will do what you want.

You can start with [this](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/02/13/982/) blog post.
[More samples](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples)

[Relevant section of documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html)

Comment: Thanks Vacuum. Do you recommend I use some sort of ESB together with Spring Integration in order to make sure the needed functionality (i.e. directory polling) is available 24 hours/day?

Comment: @balteo Spring Integration and ESB is about the same. See question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292860/spring-integration-as-embedded-alternative-to-standalone-esb

Comment: I am just concerned about the plain bootstrap class described in the blog post. How do I monitor/administer it?

Comment: @balteo to monitor work of poller you need to add JMX support or similar.

Comment: OK. I guess I am going to have a look into ESBs.. Thanks a lot for your support!

Comment: This is not a good reason to abandon S.I. for an ESB. There are many ways to run a java main() class as a system service. Take a look at Tanuki wrapper, for example.